# GDAL: Raster Intersection

Tags: gdal, intersection

I have two raster layers.

(A) is state-sized, 30m.

(B) is county-sized, 3m.

I'd like to get a new raster (C) which is the part of (A) which coincides with (B), preferably scaled to the same resolution as (B).

Is there a way to do this from the command line? From Python or C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is best done with the [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) command-line tool. The functionality also has a [GDAL Warp API](https://gdal.org/tutorials/warp_tut.html) for C++ and is exposed for Python too (see `help(gdal.ReprojectImage)` from a Python shell).

For example, using the gdalwarp command-line:

```
gdalwarp -te xmin ymin xmax ymax -tr 3 3 -r bilinear A_state_30m.tif C_county_3m.tif
```

where:

- `-te` target extents, you need to supply this from your (B) county-sized raster; try using [`gdalinfo`](https://gdal.org/gdalinfo.html) to help determine this extent
- `-tr` target resolution, 3 m
- `-r bilinear`, a good algorithm for orthophotos and DEMs, but not for others; other algorithms are available
- `A_state_30m.tif`, input (A) file
- `C_county_3m.tif`, output (C) file

Comment: I didn't get where the overlap is obtained.

Comment: @wondim this does not do any intersection. You need to specify `-te xmin ymin xmax ymax` and `-tr 3 3` based on the reference raster that needs to be matched to.