# gdalwarp bugs with extent as float?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, intersection, gdalwarp

I work with ***GDAL 2.2.1, released 2017/06/23***

I had some troubles when trying to resample GeoTiff images to make different data sources match with extent and resolution. I found an answer here: [GDAL: Raster Intersection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27694/gdal-raster-intersection)

But I identified a bug that wasn't notified here : when I use float values for the extent -te, for example with longitude / latitude values, **the result image is only filled bith NoData values** !

For instance, this gives ND image, input and output are EPSG:4326:

```
gdalwarp -te 7.5 43.5 8.5 44.5 -tr 0.005 0.005 -r bilinear input.tif output.tif
```

While this gives a correct image with values:

```
gdalwarp -te 7 43 9 45 -tr 0.005 0.005 -r bilinear input.tif output.tif
```

Is it a known bug of GDAL that anyone else has experienced?

Comment: Feels odd. Can you share some test data?

Comment: More suggestions: Add gdalinfo about the source image and try with the default resampling (nearest).

Comment: If you want to get an answer please find out some test data that you can share with others.